# How to post parameter like ' \u0001[xxxx] ' using AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, xcode, post, http-post, afnetworking

I made this, but is error [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"\u0001[xxxx]"]

```
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"\u0001[xxxx]"], @"content",
                            [NSNumber numberWithBool:anonymous],@"aaaaa",
                            nil];

return [manager POST:submitCommentUrlString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    ...

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    ...
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x1]
```

This is \u0001

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"\u0001[xxxx]"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

instead of

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"\u0001[xxxx]"]
```

in order to set object in a dictionary.

Comment: Thx, I will try this. But I find  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x1] == \u0001